# Two different definitions of condensed groupoid

Tags: ct.category-theory, groupoids, condensed-mathematics

I am searching for a condensed version of a topological groupoid and I found two possible definitions.

$\textbf{Definition 0:}$ A condensed groupoid(0) is a functor $X: \mathrm{Extr}^{\mathrm{op}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Gpd}$ such that $X(\varnothing)$ is a point groupoid and $X(S \sqcup T) = X(S) \times X(T)$. Here, $\mathrm{Extr}$ is the category of extremally disconnected sets and $\mathrm{Gpd}$ is the category of groupoids.

$\textbf{Definition 1:}$ A condensed groupoid(1) is a [groupoid object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid_object) in the category of condensed sets. This means that there are two condensed sets $O$ and $M$. The first space, $O$, functions as the objects of the groupoids, while the second space, $M$, functions as the morphisms they came along with morphisms source, target, composition, unit... satisfying the usual relations.

Are these two definitions equivalent in some sense?

Comment: Definition 0 is a bit ambiguous -- it depends on whether you defined Gpd in the weak or strong sense (i.e. as 2-category or as a 1-category). The strong sense is equivalent to Definition 1. And the relation between weak and strict versions is as usual: There is a natural functor from the strong version to the weak version, and it universally "inverts weak equivalences". (All of this holds in any topos.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Prof Scholze!